# Internationalized XML and XSL Styles

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following example XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='test.xsl'?>
<words>
<word xml:lang="en">English</word>
<word xml:lang="pl">Polish</word>
<word xml:lang="pl">Polish2</word>
<word xml:lang="en">English2</word>
</words>
```

I'm trying to style it so only the english words display.  However when I try something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each select="words/word">
                    <b><xsl:value-of select=".[lang('en')]" /></b><br />
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Nothing comes back.  I think I'm on the right track because if I have

```
<b><xsl:value-of select="." /></b><br />
```

they all come back, but I'm unsure how to do a selector on a particular language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
<xsl:for-each select="words/word[@xml:lang = 'en']">
  <b><xsl:value-of select="./text()" /></b><nr/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right track.  That's also the place to put the lang() function... <xsl:for-each select="words/word[lang('en')]">

Comment: Yes, that's also the place for it. I just didn't know about the lang() function :)